# Migrate DB Plugin: Error "The directory needs to be writable"

Tags: plugins, migration

I'm using the [migrate db plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to do some find and replaces to the database after it's been exported.

It continues to pester me with the directory isn't writeable error. I've went and chmod'd the whole /wp-content folder with the following command:

`chmod -R 777`

which i know you're not suppoose to do; but it's driving me nuts. it still has the same silly error.

Does anyone know which folder it's asking to give the correct permissions?

Comment: What host are you on?

Comment: Mediatemple Grid Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just exporting via command line. Neither answers were appropriate for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the owner of all your web directories to the user that the web server is associated with (sometimes 'www-data'). The format is:

```
chown -R username directory
```

So you would use:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data directory
```

Comment: They don't give you permissions on the host i have to do that. So i don't think that maybe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/107894/migration-to-media-temple-dv-from-gs-777-permissions-issue):

(1) Connect to your server as the root user and open up /etc/group in a text editor. (2) Find the line that appears similar to: psacln:x:2523: (3) Add the following groups (do not change the groupID number): psacln:x:2523:apache,psaftp,psaadm (4) Grant group write access to any folders (5) Restart the apache service.

Comment: It's shared hosting. You're not given access to root user or sudo powers.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your web hosting uses PHP 4, but wp-migrate-db requires PHP 5.
More specifically, the WP_Migrate_DB class only specifies a PHP5 constructor (__construct), which is never called in PHP4, so the uploads directory is not initialized and the above error is displayed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create "uploads" directory in your /wp-content folder and add the write and read permissions of www user for it (or just "chmod 777 uploads").

Comment: **Never set a public file or directory to 777.**